# Make ajax call from gsp page in grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am new to ajax. I am trying to send a request from my gsp page to controller action. But I am failing. It is not calling controller action and the page is reloading. Can anyone please look at this and help. Here is my view page bellow >>>

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ajax First Example</title>
    <g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"/>
    <script>
        function callAjax(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "returnMe",
                type:"post",
                dataType: 'json',
//            data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList), option:option, id:id}
                success: function() {
                    alert(1)
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='myForm'>
    <input type="submit" value="Call Ajax Function" onclick="callAjax()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my controller action >>>

```
def returnMe = {
    String msg = 'sdfsdf'
    render msg as JSON
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this :

```
onclick="callAjax() return false;">
```

or this one:

```
function callAjax(e){ //<-------pass the event
        e.preventDefault(); // <-----add this to prevent the default behavior
        $.ajax({
           .....
        });
}
```

Your complete ajax call as requested:

```
function callAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "returnMe",
            type:"post",
            dataType: 'json',
//          data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList), option:option, id:id}
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); //<-----this logs the data in browser's console
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert(xhr.responseText); //<----when no data alert the err msg
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. First one works for me. But it's not giving alert for the success. Only the controller's action is being called.What should I do now ?

Comment: you can try adding error function to your ajax, and see if your controller is producing `"json"` properly.

Comment: yes my json is not building properly. Now I have change it to html. It's ok now. But can you give me a link of complete ajax call structure please. thanks.