# jQuery click handler not executing AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, http-post

**Note:** I personally prefer `jQuery` instead of `$`; it's more typing but I find it more readable.

I have a simple form that lets the user enter their first/last names and email address. It has a "Save" button, that, when clicked, executes:

```
jQuery('#saveButton').click(function() {
    alert('About to Save to server');

    var validated = validateContact();
    if(!validated) {
        alert('Did not validate!');
        return;
    } else {
        alert('Validated!');
    }

    jQuery().ajax({
        url: "saveContact",
        type:"post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            contact: {
                firstName: jQuery('#firstName').val(),
                lastName: jQuery('#lastName').val(),
                emailAddress: jQuery('#emailAddress').val()
            }
        },
        success: function(result) {
            jQuery('#firstName').val("");
            jQuery('#lastName').val("");
            jQuery('#emailAddress').val("");
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

    alert('Saved to server');
});
```

When I click the "Save" button, I get several `alert` popups, including the "Validated!" message, however the script seems to die shortly after that, and I never see the "Saved to server" alert. This tells me my jQuery/AJAX call is bad. Furthermore, when I open my browser's Developer Tools, I don't see the browser actually making a network POST to my backend. In the console I don't see any errors. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong and why I'm not even seeing any network activity?

Comment: jquery -> jQuery plus you have to specify a file or a controller too.

Comment: i believe you have to specify a file: url: "saveContact.php" for example

Comment: Thanks @Dean.DePue (+1) but I'm not following you. Are you saying that I need to replace `jQuery` with `jquery->jQuery`? If so, why? Also I don't think you're right because the click handler itself is executing and firing the `alert` messages up to a certain point.

Comment: @smeeb All `jquery` needs to be `jQuery`, note the uppercase.

Comment: Thanks @Shaeldon (+1) - but my backend is actually a [Grails](https://grails.org/) app. Also, please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20209557/4009451) which is what I actually modeled my JS script from. You can see that my `url` is exactly like the `returnMe` value in that answer. Also, most importantly, The browser doesn't know whether a remote endpoint exists or not; **it should still be firing the HTTP POST and simply failing if the server can't do anything with the request.**

Comment: Replace jQuery().ajax with jQuery.ajax({...})

Comment: Thanks @JibranKhan and artm (+1 both) but see my updates - same deal changing "jquery" to "jQuery" changed nothing...

Comment: What @JibranKhan is hinting is to not use the parentheses after jQuery. So `jQuery().ajax` should be replaced with `jQuery.ajax`

Comment: Not changing the case only, but round braces after jQuery() must not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Errors in your code:

- Used jquery instead of jQuery.
- Used jQuery() instead of jQuery in calling ajax method.

JS:

```
jQuery('#saveButton').click(function () {
    alert('About to Save to server');

    var validated = true; //Changed to temporary value.
    if (!validated) {
        alert('Did not validate!');
        return;
    } else {
        alert('Validated!');
    }

    jQuery.ajax({ //Replaced jQuery() with jQuery
        url: "/saveContact", //Sample URL
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            contact: {
                firstName: jQuery('#firstName').val(), //Replaced jquery with jQuery
                lastName: jQuery('#lastName').val(), //Replaced jquery with jQuery
                emailAddress: jQuery('#emailAddress').val() //Replaced jquery with jQuery
            }
        },
        success: function (result) {
            jQuery('#firstName').val(""); //Replaced jquery with jQuery
            jQuery('#lastName').val(""); //Replaced jquery with jQuery
            jQuery('#emailAddress').val(""); //Replaced jquery with jQuery
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

    alert('Saved to server');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x2mv94vm/6/

Comment: Thanks @K K (+1) - see my updates; changing the case didn't change anything for me - script still dies in same place and no POST is sent to the server.

Comment: Maybe that's because the validateContact() returns false. Did you checked?

Comment: Thanks again @K K (+1 again) - yes I confirmed `validateContact` returns true (and I also get the "*Validated!*" alert popup to verify this).

Comment: Also, please check the url. In the fiddle itself, if you change the url the post works fine but if you don't change the url the post dies in jsfiddle too. So something is definitely wrong with post url

Answer (score 3):

Replace `jQuery().ajax` with `jQuery.ajax({...})`

Comment: Thanks @Jibran Khan (+1) - please see my updates; changing the case didn't fix this for me. The script still dies in the same place and  no HTTP POST is sent to the server...any ideas?

Comment: Not changing the case only, but round braces after jQuery() must not be included.