# how to update 2 text fields on click of a search button in the same form by fetching data from Grails Controller using AJAX in Grails 2.1.0

Tags: ajax, grails

I have a controller(SearchController) which fetches  data on clicking a search button (inside myview.gsp)  i want to populate 2 text fields present in the same myview.gsp with the data i have in my controller (SearchController) .I know i need to do ajax calling because i want to populate only 2 fields and dont want to reload the page which contains other valuable information . How can i achieve it please guide me

here is my Controller

```
def searchItem() {

    def itemFound = MyService.searchP20Code(params["item"])

    def resultMap = [:]
    if (itemFound!=null)

{



   resultMap.put("CODE",itemFound[1])
   resultMap.put("DESC",itemFound[2])

}


println "Result:"+resultMap



session.setAttribute("searchResult", resultMap)
render(view: myview" )


}
```

myview.gsp

```
          myview.gsp 


                   <div class="leftPanel filter-label">
                <a href="#" class="tt"> <g:message
                        code="Normal.label.Code" />

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightPanel filter-field-wrapper">
                <input type="text"
                    name="Code" maxlength="30"
                     value=""
                     id="i_code" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formLables">

            <div class="leftPanel filter-label">
                <a href="#" class="tt"> <g:message
                        code="Normal.label.Description" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightPanel filter-field-wrapper">
                <input type="text" 
                    name="Desc" maxlength="30"
                    onkeyup="fieldMaxlength(&#39;material_code&#39;)" value=""

                    id="i_description" />
            </div>
        </div>



                <g:actionSubmit 

                    value="${message(code:'Normal.button.search', default: 'Search Code')}"
                    action="searchItem" />
```

please help my how can i update only these two text fields in myview.gsp onclicking search button using ajax .I am using grails 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/grails-ajax-examples.html) you can find a detailed example with Grails build-in Ajax support.

You can also use JQuery ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209460/make-ajax-call-from-gsp-page-in-grails))

EDIT:

Your controller needs to look like this:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class ExampleController {
    ....    

    def searchItem() {

        def itemFound = MyService.searchP20Code(params["item"])

        def resultMap = [:]
        if (itemFound!=null) {
            resultMap.put("CODE",itemFound[1])
            resultMap.put("DESC",itemFound[2])
        }


        println "Result:"+resultMap



        //session.setAttribute("searchResult", resultMap)
        render(resultMap as JSON )


    }
}
```

and your gsp

```
<head>
...
    <g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-{WRITE_YOUR_VERSION_HERE}.js"/>
    <script>
        function callAjax(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "example/search",
                type:"post",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("input[name='Code']").val(data.CODE);
                    $("input[name='Desc']").val(data.DESC);
                }
            });
        }            
    </script>
...
</head>
<body>
....
    <input type="submit" value="Call Ajax Function" onclick="callAjax()">
....
</body>
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your answer but i am a new  to both grails & Ajax . :( could u pls show me how to do it in my example ! Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: In the examples you have refered the Programmer is displaying the data fetched from the Ajax call in a separate Template but i want to display in the same page i.e myview.gsp

Comment: I added an example with more details. The takeaway is that you need to return JSON and make sure you have jquery installed. Let me know if you have any problems with it. I tested the gsp with my dummy controller and grails 2.5.0, but it should work for you too.

Comment: Hi Ivojnovic sir .. in my case it is just refreshed  the page but showing no data in the fields ..yes i have jquery installed i am importing the .js file as mentioned by you ! Please help !

Comment: Add an argument to the callAjax method (e) and in the first line add: e.preventDefault(); I will update my answer

Comment: Hello sir thanks for the solution !! i did input type = button and it stopped refreshing the page ...Now in the AJAX call i modified like this since i need to send the value of textfield named 'Code' as parameter to the search action of the controller var v_Code= document.getElementById("code").value
     alert("Hello"+v_Code)
     
     $.ajax({
         url:"search,?Code='"+v_Code+"'"
         type:"post",    am i sending this parameter correctly ? a correct url parameter type will solve all my problem

Comment: You can use $.ajax({ url: 'search', type: 'get', data: { Code : v_Code }  })

Comment: Hello  i tried both 

function callAjax(){
  var v_Code= document.getElementById("code").value
     alert("Hello"+v_Code)
   

  
     $.ajax({
         url:"search?Code='"+v_Code+"'",
         type:'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {   

             alert(data)
             console.log(data.Desc)
             $("input[name='CODE']").val(data.Code)
             $("input[name='DESC']").val(data.Desc)
         }
     });
 }  



and using data parameters but unable to call the SearchController :( please help

Comment: Did you set type to 'get' when using data parameters? What error did you get? Can you reach the controller?

Comment: Hi ! now things are working fine !! I had to clear my browser cache ! But i have a small doubt ! How can we display a message if the data is not found i.e data is Null .. i tried this  if(data==null)
               {

            $( ".message" ).text( "Data Not Found" );
               }    it didnt work

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Can you please accept the answer? For the null message: what is the type of .message element? Is that another field or a label?

Comment: Thanks a ton! without you i could never have moved an inch in my project ! This is my first ever college project !!  What i want now is if data received is null then show a message box that "No data Found"

Comment: Make sure that the `data` parameter is really `null`, and not only the `data.desc`. I am not sure if you already have a field where you want your message to show. If you don't, you can add a new html element below the field, like: `$('#i_description').after('<p id = "no-data-msg">Data Not Found</p>')`, and when you want to remove it later: `$('#no-data-msg').remove()`. Easier approach is to just show an alert box with `alert('Data Not Found!')`